# Download size is not specified

Tags: php, http-headers, download

I want to download a PDF file:

```
$output = RP_MAIN . 'docbook/data/myfile' . $_SESSION["sess_code_user"] . '.pdf'; // this is the pdf file I want to download
$file_size = filesize($output);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-type: text/enriched");
header("Content-length: $file_size");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.'manuel.'. $extension .''.'"');
ob_clean();
flush();
print($output);
exit();
```

The PDF file exists in the system and it has 25 Kb size. But the problem is that the download popup (Internet Download Manager) has a blank field in the size field.

What's wrong with my code? How can I solve this issue?

---

**EDIT :**
The pdf file is created from an ajax call, then on the success of the ajax then the download is started :

```
var request = $.ajax({
        data: donne,
        type: "POST",
        url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX_TACHE ?>TacheCreerPdfAjax.php" , // this creates the pdf file
        async: false
    });

    request.done(function() { 
        $('#corps').html(request.responseText);

        if(fichier == "pdf" || fichier == "rtf")
            window.location.href = '<?php echo PAGE_TACHE ?>?action=TacheGenererManuelExec&fichier=' + fichier ; // this starts the download
    ...
    }
```

So when launching the download then there is an error stating that the format of source is not pdf !

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$output = RP_MAIN . 'docbook/data/myfile' . $_SESSION["sess_code_user"] . '.pdf';    
if (is_file($output)) {
    $size = filesize($output);
    if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        $type = mime_content_type($output);
    } elseif (function_exists('finfo_file')) {
        $info = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $type = finfo_file($info, $output);
        finfo_close($info);
    }
    if ($type == '') {
        $type = "application/force-download";
    }
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . $size);
    readfile($output);
    exit;
} else {
    return false;
}
```